# How to correctly use UrlEncode and Decode

Tags: c#, azure, encoding, urlencode, urldecode

So I have a file I am uploading to azure blob storage:

> C:\test folder\A+B\testfile.txt

and two extension methods that help encode my path to make sure it is given a valid azure storage blob name

```
    public static string AsUriPath(this string filePath)
    {
        return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(filePath.Replace('\\', '/'));
    }
    public static string AsFilePath(this string uriPath)
    {
        return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uriPath.Replace('/', '\\'));
    }
```

So when upload the file I encode it `AsUriPath` and get the name `test%20folder\A+B\testfile.txt`
but when I try to get this back as a file path I get `test folder\A B\testfile.txt` which is obviously not the same (the `+` has been dropped)

What's the correct way to use UrlEncode and UrlDecode to ensure you will get the same information decoded as you originally encoded?

Comment: Because a `+` is seen as an already encoded space. What does `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you use `WebUtility.UrlEncode` instead of `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`

If you check out the [docs on HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see that it states:

> Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode.

I've coded up a simple example which can be pasted into a console app (you'll need to reference the System.Web assembly)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = @"C:\test folder\A+B\testfile.txt";
    var encoded = WebUtility.UrlEncode(filePath.Replace('\\', '/'));
    var decoded = WebUtility.UrlDecode(encoded.Replace('/', '\\'));
    Console.WriteLine(decoded);
}
```

Run it here at this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fg6Pv4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. looks like UrlEncode works ok. Is there any difference between `WebUtility` and `HttpUtility`?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/05/21/beware-webutility-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode/

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Uri class to properly encode a path: [MSDN System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try the below on your path and use the debugger to inspect:

```
        var myUri = new System.Uri("http://someurl.com/my special path + is this/page?param=2");
        var thePathAndQuery = myUri.PathAndQuery;
        var theAbsolutePath = myUri.AbsolutePath;
        var theAbsoluteUri = myUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: Could you expand on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Try it on a file path too - C:\..\.. etc