# trouble serving .mp3 files from .aspx to IE browsers using < audio>

Tags: c#, asp.net, mp3, html5-audio

I have a problem with this .aspx c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request["url"];
    string type = Request["ext"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] file = client.DownloadData(url);

        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
            Response.BinaryWrite(file);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in all browsers except IE. In IE, the < audio> tag player shows a cryptic message saying "Invalid Source". No console errors or warnings. I'm guessing I have a subtle error in my Response settings. Below is the < audio> markup, but like I said, it works on every browser except IE. I've gone way out of my way to try to make it work on IE -- once again, the most difficult browser to work with by far. After all these years, it's beyond heartbreaking. What the hell are people DOING at Microsoft?

```
<audio controls="true" preload="none">
  <source src="http://localhost:8056/web/Recordings/RE4cdf6a142506328787e9c88cbf7c4885.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
Your browser does not support HTML5 audio. Please consider upgrading your browser to the latest version.
</audio>
```

Comment: check the answers here to see if this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817266/how-to-correctly-use-urlencode-and-decode otherwise do a google search on `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to see if you are perhaps doing something incorrectly

Comment: Thanks, but if the decoding/encoding was bad, wouldn't that affect all browsers, not just IE? I would think the error is, like i mentioned, a Response setting. Like, maybe I'm missing a header or using a header incorrectly?

Comment: maybe you have special characters that are being interpreted differently in IE

Comment: OK, I will check this out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE are you using?. HTML5 is compatible with IE 9+.
You will require the HTML5shiv to provide compatibility for IE Browsers older than IE 9.

If using IE 9 you should use something like this:

```
<!-- Display the audio player with control buttons. -->
<audio src="http://localhost:8056/web/Recordings/RE4cdf6a142506328787e9c88cbf7c4885.mp3" controls autoplay loop> 
    HTML5 audio not supported
</audio>
```

**Note:**  If you are developing on an intranet and have rendering issues for HTML5, you can add  to the  block of a webpage to force Internet Explorer to use the latest standards. If you prefer, configure your web development server to send a meta http-equiv-“X-UA-Compatible” header with IE=edge instead.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589529(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this info, but I am using the latest IE 11 with Dev Tools that say the version is "Edge," which I assume is 11. I tried the meta tag, too. I really think the issue must be a Response setting, because I can't find any examples of how to serve .mp3/.mp4 using c# to set the Response values.  For example, I don't know if I should use Response.BinaryWrite() or Response.WriteFile().

Comment: My guess is that if the issue is in the response it wouldn't work in any browser because data is not sent correctly from the server side. You mentioned it works good with all browsers but IE, then need to check client side specifically for IE.

Comment: I think there is some wiggle-room with good browsers, because they'll look at headers and make certain decisions that are sensible. For example, even though I was originally serving a Content-Disposition of "attachment" -- which normally would open a Save As... dialog -- the <audio> tag overrode that and the browsers saw the mp3's as inline content rather than downloadable files. Similarly, I had a Content-Type of "application/ms-download", which all browsers interpreted to be audio/mpeg, again because of its use in an < audio > tag.

Comment: All of this is to say I believe it is quite possible to have a "bad" header that other browsers (not IE) are smart enough to recover from.